# android setOnTouchListener behavior different on android 2.3 and 4.1

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I use `setOnTouchListener` to capture `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to move a view when I tap on it.

Bt works fine on Samsung S3 (4.1.1) but not works(can not capture the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` ) on another android 2.3.3.

Any comment helps, Thanks.

=> => =>
After Log.d(), both `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and "MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE" captured, but on Android 4.1.1 the view can be moved when "MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE", but on 2.3.3, the view does not move. Do not know why. It seems findViewById(R.id.layoutMapMemoPhoto).invalidate() not work on 2.3.3.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {    

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = null;    
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();    
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();    

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {    
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:    
       lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();    
       yDeltaImageView = Y - lParams.topMargin;    
       Log.d("DOWN");    
       break;    


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:    
       lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();    

       lParams.topMargin = Y - yDeltaImageView;    
       v.setLayoutParams(lParams);    
       Log.d("MOVE");    
       break;    
  }    

findViewById(R.id.id_of_parent_view).invalidate();    


return true;  
}
```

Comment: I would Log.d() all MotionEvents that come and see what really happens. Probably, there is another kind of notification about movement.

Comment: After Log.d(), both MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and "MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE" captured, but on Android 4.1.1 the view can be moved when "MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE", but on 2.3.3, the view does not move. Do not know why. It seems findViewById(R.id.R.id.id_of_parent_view).invalidate() not work on 2.3.3.